# Error installing dbt (data build tool) using Poetry

Tags: python-poetry, dbt

I'm trying to use poetry to install `dbt`, but I keep getting this error:

```
  File \C:\Users\mkleinbort\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\7b\3a\54\42ce43b579bda01b9d79022fb733811594441e7a32e9f9a5a98f672bdc\pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl does not exist
```

Notes:

1. I'm using Python 3.9
2. Other packages installed fine

Any ideas on how to move forward?

To clarify, I can install `dbt` with pip install in the poetry environment, but if I do that it is not tracked by poetry in the `pyproject.toml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Hi from the documentation especially on Windows, it is recommended to create a virtual env first.

> python3 -m venv dbt-env
> source dbt-env/bin/activate
> pip install dbt

This should work.

Comment: To clarify, I can install dbt with pip install in the poetry environment, but if I do that it is not tracked by poetry in the `pyproject.toml` file.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `poetry add dbt-core`? I think with pip it will install just the dbt module but not the dependencies. Using poetry add dbt-core it should install dbt along with all the dependencies associated with it.

Hope this works!